# Gitlab error while listing image tags: GraphQL::IntegerEncodingError (Integer out of bounds: 7831330474

Tags: graphql, gitlab

We have just updated our Gitlab to version 13.7.1. Our container registry was working fine but after the upgrade, we are getting the following screen while accessing the tags of one of our projects (It works well in a different project). We have gitlab starter license.

What I have observed is that there are some browser console errors and some production.log errors as well.

**Errors In Browser Console**

```
vue.esm.js:1897 TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at fn (details_header.vue?4c37:1)
    at Object.r [as imageName] (vue.esm.js:2599)
    at render (sprintf.js:103)
    at vue.esm.js:3067
    at $t (vue.esm.js:3240)
    at vue.esm.js:3431
    at qt (vue.esm.js:3362)
    at e._c (vue.esm.js:3500)
    at fn (details_header.vue?4c37:1)
    at r (vue.esm.js:2599)
```

**Errors In production.log**

```
GraphQL::IntegerEncodingError (Integer out of bounds: 7831330474.
Consider using ID or GraphQL::Types::BigInt instead.):
  lib/gitlab/graphql/generic_tracing.rb:40:in `with_labkit_tracing'
  lib/gitlab/graphql/generic_tracing.rb:30:in `platform_trace'
  lib/gitlab/graphql/generic_tracing.rb:40:in `with_labkit_tracing'
  lib/gitlab/graphql/generic_tracing.rb:30:in `platform_trace'
  app/graphql/gitlab_schema.rb:43:in `multiplex'
  app/controllers/graphql_controller.rb:68:in `execute_multiplex'
  app/controllers/graphql_controller.rb:32:in `execute'
  ee/lib/gitlab/ip_address_state.rb:10:in `with'
  ee/app/controllers/ee/application_controller.rb:44:in `set_current_ip_address'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:494:in `set_current_admin'
  lib/gitlab/session.rb:11:in `with_session'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:485:in `set_session_storage'
  lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:73:in `with_locale'
  lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:79:in `with_user_locale'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:479:in `set_locale'
  lib/gitlab/error_tracking.rb:52:in `with_context'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:544:in `sentry_context'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:472:in `block in set_current_context'
  lib/gitlab/application_context.rb:54:in `block in use'
  lib/gitlab/application_context.rb:54:in `use'
  lib/gitlab/application_context.rb:21:in `with_context'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:464:in `set_current_context'
  lib/gitlab/metrics/elasticsearch_rack_middleware.rb:16:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/rails_queue_duration.rb:33:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_middleware.rb:16:in `block in call'
  lib/gitlab/metrics/transaction.rb:56:in `run'
  lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_middleware.rb:16:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/jira/middleware.rb:19:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:20:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/etag_caching/middleware.rb:21:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/multipart.rb:234:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only/controller.rb:50:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only.rb:18:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/same_site_cookies.rb:27:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/handle_malformed_strings.rb:21:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/basic_health_check.rb:25:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/handle_ip_spoof_attack_error.rb:25:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/request_context.rb:23:in `call'
  config/initializers/fix_local_cache_middleware.rb:9:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/metrics/requests_rack_middleware.rb:76:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/release_env.rb:12:in `call'
```

Any help is much appreciated. I have tried shortening the name length of image tag but with no success.

Thanks in advance.